# Riemann-esque sums (complex analysis)

Tags: complex-analysis

I have been struggling to prove the following statement:

"Let $\gamma:[t_0,t_1] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a $C^1$ curve. For any $N \in \mathbb{N}$ and $k \in (0,N]$ define $t_N^k := \bigg(1 - \dfrac{k}{N}\bigg)t_0 + \dfrac{k}{N}t_1$

Show that for every continous function $f:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ the following Riemann type sums converge as below: $$\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}f(\gamma(t_N^k))(\gamma(t_N^{k+1}) - \gamma(t_N^k)) \longrightarrow \int_{\gamma}f(z)dz$$ As $N \rightarrow \infty$ "

Here's what I have so far, but it's incomplete (even though I can see some idea of showing it):

First thing to note is that $\gamma$ is continous on a closed domain; thus, by the partition defined by $t_N^k$ above, we can invoke the mean value theorem on each interval $[t_N^k,t_N^{k + 1}]$. Namely, $\exists s \in [t_N^k,t_N^{k + 1}]$ s.t. $\gamma(t_N^{k + 1}) - \gamma(t_N^k) = \gamma'(s)ds$ where $ds = t_N^{k + 1} - t_N^k$. So we can rewrite the sum as follows: $$S_N := \sum_{k = 0}^{N-1}f(\gamma(t_N^k))\gamma'(s)ds$$ Also we can rewrite the line integral as a sum of integrals over each increment $ds$ as follows: $$I_N := \sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\bigg(\int_{t_N^k}^{t_N^{k+1}}f(\gamma(s))\gamma'(s)ds\bigg)$$ Taking the absolute difference of these terms yields: $$|I_N - S_N| = \bigg|\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\bigg(\int_{t_N^k}^{t_N^{k+1}}f(\gamma(s)) - f(\gamma(t_N^k)))\gamma'(s)ds\bigg) \bigg| \\ \leq \sup_{s \in [t_N^k,t_N^{k+1}]}|f(\gamma(s)) - f(\gamma(t_N^k))|\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\int_{t_N^k}^{t_N^{k+1}}|\gamma'(s)|ds$$

And then from here I'm not sure how to completely finish this off. I assume it takes one or two more steps to show this converges to zero, but I don't know how to do it exactly. Could somebody guide me there?

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: You are almost finished, use uniform continuity of $f \circ \gamma$ to show that the $\sup |\cdots |$ quantity goes to zero as $N \to \infty$.

Comment: Ahh thank you very much for your assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you are defining $\int_{\gamma}f(z)dz$ by $I=\int_{t_0}^{t_1} f(\gamma(t)) \gamma'(t) dt$.

Let $M = \sup_{t \in [t_0,t_1]} |\gamma'(t)|$.

Since $\phi = f \circ \gamma $ is continuous, it is uniformly continuous on $[t_0,t_1]$. Let $\epsilon>0$  and let $\delta>0$ be such that if $|s-t|<\delta$, then $|\phi(s)-\phi(t)| < \epsilon$.

Pick a partition $P=(s_0=t_0, s_1,...,s_n=t_1)$ such that successive points are less than $\delta$ apart and let $\tilde{\phi} = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \phi(s_k) 1_{[s_k,s_{k+1})}$. Then we have
$\sup_{t \in [t_0,t_1)} |\phi(t) - \tilde{\phi}(t)| < \epsilon$ (note that
$t_1$ is excluded from the $\sup$).

Hence
$| \int_{t_0}^{t_1} \phi(t) \gamma'(t) dt  - \int_{t_0}^{t_1} \tilde{\phi}(t) \gamma'(t) dt| < \epsilon M (t_1-t_0)$.

Now note that $\int_{t_0}^{t_1} \phi(t) dt = \int_{\gamma}f(z)dz$ and
$\int_{t_0}^{t_1} \tilde{\phi}(t) dt = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f(\gamma(s_k))\int_{s_k}^{s_{k+1}} \gamma'(t)dt = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f(\gamma(s_k))(\gamma(s_k)-\gamma(s_{k+1})) dt$.

If you choose $s_k = t^k_N$, with ${t_1-t_0 \over N} < \delta$, then this gives
$|\int_{\gamma}f(z)dz- \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f(\gamma(t^k_N))(\gamma(t^{k+1}_N)-\gamma(t^k_N)) dt| < \epsilon M (t_1-t_0)$.
Since $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary, we have the desired result.

Comment: This is very comprehensive and very useful. Thank you very much for your help. One question, why is $t_1$ excluded from the sup? (Probably has an obvious answer) :P

Comment: @JohnnyBreen: A slight laziness on my part: The way I defined $\tilde{\phi}$, we have $\tilde{\phi}(t_1) = 0$, which may be quite different from $\phi(t_1)$ (since I used $[s_k,s_{k+1})$). This could be repaired easily by adding $\phi(s_n) 1_{ \{ s_{n} \}}$ to the definition of $\tilde{\phi}$, but I was lazy :-). Since we only care what happens under the integral, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

The MVT doesn't hold for curves unfortunately. But it looks like you have some good ideas. I would look at

$$[\gamma (t_{k+1}) - \gamma (t_{k})] - \gamma'(t_k)(t_{k+1}-t_k)= \int_{t_k}^{t_{k+1}} [\gamma'(t)-\gamma'(t_k)]\,dt.$$

Because $\gamma'$ is continuous, it is unifomly continuous. So if the partition is fine enough, that last integral, in absolute value, will be $< \epsilon\cdot(t_{k+1} - t_{k})$ for all $k.$